# Blazor Server-Size with Localized Resource in another project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, localization, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-localization

I’m trying to use the [localization feature of ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in my Blazor app. I want to use IStringLocalizer so that I automatically detect the browser language to adapt to the user’s language.
My solution consists of several projects and for cleanliness I wanted to gather the resource files in one and the same project (app.core) for all my other projects.
you can see an example of my architecture :

```
solution app
|-- app.project1
|-- app.project2
|-- app.core
|   |-- Resources
|       |-- Localization
|           |-- project1
|           |-- project2
|           |-- web
|               |-- Pages
|                   |-- Index.en.resx
|                   |-- Index.fr.resx
|-- app.web
    |-- Pages
        |-- Index.razor
```

Resources related to the web project are located in the core project in the folder Resources > Localization > web.

I have looked at several existing questions before to orient myself, but I have not found a solution to my problem (or maybe I'm bad lol) :

- [Asp.Net Core Localized Resource in Separate Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044458/asp-net-core-localized-resource-in-separate-assembly/)
- [.NET Core - Globalization and Localization - Class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010240/net-core-globalization-and-localization-class-library)
- [Localization in external class libraries in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167350/localization-in-external-class-libraries-in-asp-net-core)
- [Support localization resources in a separate assembly](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8739)

When I put my resources in the same project, it works so it’s just that I can’t figure out how to do it when it’s in another project.

What I tried: In my web project in `Configureservice` I have `.AddLocalization()` and `.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opt => ...)` and in `Configure` I have `app.UseRequestLocalization()`. In my core project I created an `AssemblyInfo.cs` with `[assembly: ResourceLocation("Resources/Localization/web")]` and `[assembly: RootNamespace("app")]`
(and other names like `app.web`, or `app.core`) but it doesn’t seem to work.

I don't like the solution to do dummy .cs for each .resx, I don't like to have useless classes.

I hope my problem is understandable and my English too. Thank you in advance for your answers, this is the first time I’ve come to ask for help here!

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do this recently. Most of the needed information has been gathered from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Here's my solution structure:

```
solution app
|-- BlazorApp
|   |-- Localization
|       |-- MyTextsLocalizer.cs
|-- MyLib
|   |-- MyTexts.cs
|   |-- Localization
|       |-- MyTexts.resx
|       |-- MyTexts.cz.resx
```

## MyLib

I wanted to have all the resource keys to be available as an `enum`. `MyTexts` is an enum that is being localized by with the resource files.

### MyTexts.cs

```cs
namespace MyLib
{
    public enum MyTexts
    {
        HiThere
    }
}
```

### Localization/MyTexts.resx

This file contains translation for the `enum` values. Only one translation in this example:
key: HiThere, value: Hi there

### Localization/MyTexts.cz.resx

This file contains translation for the `enum` values. Only one translation in this example:
key: HiThere, value: Ahoj

## BlazorApp

### Localization/MyTextsLocalizer.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using MyLib;
using MyLib.Localization;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BlazerApp.Localization
{
    public class MyTextsLocalizer
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

        public MyTextsLocalizer(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {
            var type = typeof(MyTextsLoc);
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
            _localizer = factory.Create(nameof(MyTextsLoc), assemblyName.Name);
        }

        public string Localize(MyTexts myTexts)
        {
            return _localizer.GetString(myTexts.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

### Startup.cs

I've added the following code to the `ConfigureServices` method.

*Note that the `options.ResourcesPath = "Localization"` is important. The path has to be the path to where your resource files are located in the library. It doesn't work with an incorrect path.*

```cs
services.AddLocalization(options =>
{
    options.ResourcesPath = "Localization";
});
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("cz")
};
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

services.AddSingleton<MyTextsLocalizer>();
```

### Index.razor

The localizer is used in a razor component like this:

```
@page "/"

@using BlazerApp.Localization
@using MyLib

@inject MyTextsLocalizer loc

<h1>@loc.Localize(MyTexts.HiThere)</h1>
```