# modify App_GlobalResources file force the application to restart

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, application-restart, app-globalresources

As the title said, if I update the values from `App_GlobalResources` file, the application will restart. Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to prevent it.
According the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx):

> When you make a change to a default resource file, either local or global, ASP.NET recompiles the resources **and restarts** the ASP.NET application. This can affect the overall performance of your site. If you add satellite resource files, it does not cause a recompilation of resources, but the ASP.NET application **will restart**.

Since the resources are considered static data, any changes of them leads to the restart of the ASP.NET application.

More information:
[Editing resource files without recompiling ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782899/editing-resource-files-without-recompiling-asp-net-application)
[ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can prevent the restart but on changes on all configuration files. I could not find away to do it only to the `App_GlobalResources`  file.

See this answer :

[How to prevent an ASP.NET application restarting when the web.config is modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified/31470150#31470150)