# ASPHow to read Resources from Resx file when its build type is content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dll, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP .NET CORE app. In this App i'm trying to read resources from Resx file when its build type is content. For this i used [Globalization and localization method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1). I know that the problem is with this build type the resx file is not included in the DLL when compiling, and this is why when using embedded resource build type it works for me. However i'm trying to create a Resx file in which the user can modify it without redepoying the whole solution which is feasible only in content build type.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533984/7780428?