# Razor Pages Cannot Read File with build action "Content" Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I have a resources file name "Index.en-US.resx", initially it was "embedded resources" build action and it worked well in localization.

But when it is "embedded resources", it compiled it into `.dll` file.
In my case, users are able to modify the content of `.resx` file from time to time.
It cannot be `.dll` file after published.

Is there anyway to read the `.resx` file as "content" (since it will not be compiled into `.dll`) ?

Comment: Do you want to modify the resouces file after project compiled? If your question is this, you can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782899/editing-resource-files-without-recompiling-asp-net-application).

Comment: Setting build action to content didn't work for me, maybe Razor only can read embedded resources?

Comment: Do you want to read this resource file like a static file after published?

Comment: Yes, but not as `dll`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your `.resx` file to be compiled into `dll` after published, I think you can put it in your `wwwroot`, Because `wwwroot` is where static files are stored, the project will not compile it as a `dll`, As follow. You can see the resource file is not be compiled in dll after published.

[image]

[image]

[image]